# Strange response when running MySQL 5.7 execution via command line on MS Server 2012 r2

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have a strange issue when trying to execute a .sql file from CMD line on windows server 2012 R2.

I was trying to execute a sql query that deletes the content of a table & re-populates it from an XML file. The SQL side of things works fine when executed in MySQL work bench. I'm trying to get it to work in cmd line before setting the .bat file up as a scheduled task to run daily.

The line I am running is:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u Blah db_name -p "blah blah" -h localhost < C:\Shares\BATCH-FILES\sql-import.sql
```

It seems as though the batch file does run but basically reads the arguments displays all of the variables & then stops.

If I run from task scheduler, the task scheduler action step returns:

> Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Customer DB Import" , instance "{39237444-afdd-4c6a-9c93-d5b247f9537f}" , action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 2147942401.

From what I understand the error relates to a file path or permissions issue?

Is there anything obvious I'm not doing? I have read a few similar articles on here but haven't found any in a similar scenario.

Comment: @RaymondNijland But this is on MySQL not MS SQL? Its running on a windows server but is MySQL 5.7?

Comment: '-p' should be followed by password, without space: `-ppassword`. Otherwise you can use `--password="password"`.

Comment: @MichaelO. Thanks very much, that sorted it running in CMD line. I'm going to try this in task Scheduler now but would hope this has sorted it.

Comment: @MichaelO. That sorted it in task Scheduler too... Thanks for that. Good to know I wasn't too far off & thanks for the assistance. I'll note it for future.